# Non-vanishing holomorphic functions and probability measures

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, positive-definite

Take a set of positive numbers $1\geq a_i\geq 0$ for $i=1,\cdots, n$. What are the necessary (and/or) sufficient conditions on $a_i$ so that $f(\tau)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^\tau$ has no zeros on the complex $\tau$ plane?
Or more generally what is known about the solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^\tau=0$? What is the name of this function in Math, or where is it studied? I think it should come up in the interpolation theory of $L_p$ spaces, but I found no discussion of the zeros of the function.

For the physicists: I am asking what are the necessary (and/or) sufficient conditions on energy levels so that free energy is an analytic function of complex inverse temperature.

Comment: Do you know about Hadamard's factorisation theorem?

Comment: Great point. Let's see if I understand.
It is true that if all $a_i$ are non-zero and $n$ is finite we have an entire function. Then, the Hadamard factorization theorem says that if this entire function has no zeros and its grows like $O(e^{(|\tau|^m)})$ as $\tau\to\infty$ then $f(\tau)$ has the form $f(\tau)=e^{\sum_{k=1}^qc_k \tau^k}$ for some $k\leq m$. Is that right?
Let's say $a_i$ are generic positive numbers then I guess we expect that the growth of $f(\tau)$  is bounded by $\max( a_{max}, 1/a_{min} )$, right? Unfortunately, I still do not see how to find constraints on $a_i$.

Comment: Now, I am confused. Are we saying that it can only be $f(\tau)=n e^{c\tau}$?

Comment: That, or you have zeros. If $$f(\tau) = \sum_{k = 1}^n b_k e^{\lambda_k\tau}$$ with $b_k, \lambda_k \in \mathbb{C}$, then $f$ is an entire function of order at most $1$. Hence if $f$ has no zeros, then $f(\tau) = be^{\lambda\tau}$, and for all $\mu \neq \lambda$ we must have $\sum_{\lambda_k = \mu} b_k = 0$. In your set-up, assuming $a_i \neq 0$ for all $i$, $f$ is zero-free iff all $a_i$ are equal. One can rule out finitely many zeros similarly. Thus either you have infinitely many zeros, or all terms are equal.